# Entity template file/suggestion not working

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I've created a entity template file but it's not working.   I've looked at the theme registry and I can see the template file is in there but it's not getting applied for some reason.

Thank for you help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure this out and it was relatively simple.   I added a preprocess function to template.php for entities and added the template file back in to theme_hook_suggestions array.

```
function theme_preprocess_entity(&$variables){
  $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'entity__your_template_name';
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me :(

Comment: @MariusIlie you need to have the [Entity API](https://drupal.org/project/entity) module enabled in order for this to work.